# Ajax call inside shortcode

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I am currently despairing of including an ajax call in a shortcode.

The admin-ajax is called but my main problem is, that the post data in the actual ajax call is always empty although I actually pass the variables with the wp_localize_script function. Since a similar ajax call works in another place ( but without shortcode), I suspect that ajax calls in shortcodes need to be built and structured differently. I just have no idea how...

In my plugin I use the following code:

**plugin.php**

```
<?php

/**
 *  Plugin Name: Test Plugin
 *  Description: Test
 *  Version: 0.1
 *  Author: Cool name
 *  Author URI: https://www.xyz.de
 */

add_shortcode("oc_product_widget","oc_product_widget");

function oc_product_widget() {

    $var1 = "var1";
    $var2 = "var2";

    wp_enqueue_script('products_price_page_ajax_js', plugins_url('js/price_page_ajax.js', __FILE__));

    wp_localize_script('products_price_page_ajax_js', 'products_price_page_ajax_js', array(
        'ajaxurl'       => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
        'var1'          => $var1,
        'var2'          => $var2,
    ));

}

add_action("wp_ajax_get_price_page", "get_price_page");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_get_price_page", "get_price_page" );

function get_price_page(){
    include_once (plugins_url("ajax/get_price.php", __FILE__));
    wp_die();
}

?>
```

**price_page_ajax.js**

```
(function($) {

    $(document).ready(function () {

        var ajaxurl = products_price_page_ajax_js.ajaxurl;
        var var1 = products_price_page_ajax_js.var1
        var var2 = products_price_page_ajax_js.var2

        $.ajax({ // Ajax call
            url: ajaxurl, // Ajax site
            data: {
                var1: var1,
                var2: var2,
                action:"get_price_page"
            },
            type: 'post'
        }).done(function (responseData) {

            var resultObject = JSON.parse(responseData);

        }).fail(function () {

            console.log('AJAX call failed');

        });

    })

})( jQuery );
```

**get_price.php**

```
<?php

$var1 = $_POST["var1"];
$var2 = $_POST["var2"];
...
...

// admin-ajax.php is throwing
// Warning: Undefined array key "var1" in ...get_price.php on line ...
// &
// Warning: Undefined array key "var2" in ...get_price.php on line ...

?>
```

Comment: So if the `'ajaxurl'` key in your wp_localize_script call caused `products_price_page_ajax_js.ajaxurl` to exit in the client-side JavaScript - then what key should be present, so that `products_price_page_ajax_js.cnum` gets created as well ...? You used the key `var1`, which would mean that `products_price_page_ajax_js.var1` will be created.

Comment: products_price_page_ajax_js.cnum was my fault. I forgot to change the key for this example. Now its products_price_page_ajax_js.var1 and products_price_page_ajax_js.var2.

Comment: So, still not working? Have you logged `products_price_page_ajax_js` to console. to see what it actually contains at that point?

Comment: Why are you doing whatever needs doing here, via a shortcode to begin with? With this kind of setup, I suppose it can be used only once per page, otherwise "localizing" this script will not work properly, but overwrite `products_price_page_ajax_js` each time.

Comment: Nah, its still not working. I console logged products_price_page_ajax_js and it contains all the needed values I´ve set before. But in get_price.php the post is completely empty.

Comment: Can't see what should be wrong here. When you inspect the request in your browser dev tools, does it look like it's sending the correct parameters there?

Comment: Yes, inside the dev tools, I can see the parameters. But for some reasons the post is always empty. I´ve tried to put `add_action("wp_ajax_get_price_page", "get_price_page");` and `add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_get_price_page", "get_price_page" );` inside the shortcode but then the admin-ajax returns 400 http error.

Comment: Whether the code came from a shortcode or not, should not make much difference - the JavaScript executes on document ready, and by that time it doesn't really matter any more, what caused the creation of the HTML/JS output. But I don't understand what the purpose of the whole thing is supposed to be to begin with - _why_ do you need to send values you very obviously knew on the server side already, to the client and then from there back to the server? And on top of that on page load, without even any user interaction.

Comment: The `get_price.php` is doing much more in reality. This whole code is simplified to show the basic problem with my post data being empty... The ajax call is needed because we fetch a custom customer price from our internal erp server. Due to the age and complexity of the server the query can take quite a long time. Without the Ajax call the page will hang in the loading state until the query is finished or timeout. But this whole process is absolutely irrelevant for the problem because the `get_price.php` already has empty post parameters at the beginning...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the post parameters was discarded after the `include_once`. Why exactly this happens I don't know exactly yet. Maybe someone can clarify this.

In detail:

**Wrong**

```
function get_price_page(){
    include_once (plugins_url("ajax/get_price.php", __FILE__));
    wp_die();
}
```

**Correct**

```
function get_price_page(){
    $var1 = $_POST["var1"];
    $var2 = $_POST["var2"];
    ...
    ...
    wp_die();
}
```